# PHP file doesn't get $_POST from Javascript application

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to get a $_POST in a php file and sent from a Javascript application but i can't display it.
My Javascript application seems working, i tested on RequestBin and the site can get and displays the content of the $_POST (a simple String).

The problem seems coming from the PHP file.

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
    $data = htmlspecialchars($_POST['data']);
    echo $data;
} else {
    echo "0";
}

?>
```

'data' is a simple String.
It gets the $_POST then an ajax code will try to display it :

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
 function repeat(){
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "file.php",
   success:function(data){
    console.log("test data : "+data);
   }
  });
  $(document.body).delay(1000).show(1, repeat);
 }
 repeat();
});
</script>
```

However, I never display the content of the $_POST.

Help would be appreciated, thx !

Comment: are you trying cross-server ajax ?

Comment: have you tried to debug your jQuery? i.e. log something before ajax.

Comment: My Ajax code is in the same server as my php file. He's just waiting to be called by the PHP to actualize the web page

Comment: where is your Java code?

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` value in ajax is undefined which is why your not seeing it. `$_POST` is showing your value in php because `data` is defined there.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
    function repeat(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "file.php",

            data: NEEDS VALUE HERE TO GET BELOW,

            success:function(data){
                console.log("test data : "+data);
            }
        });
        $(document.body).delay(1000).show(1, repeat);
    }
    repeat();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think that it is the problem because every second the console display the "test data : 0". So it seems the ajax get the data from the php.